# Background opacity and blur over another image

Tags: jquery, css, blur, translucency

I am working on one thing and instead of using big images I would preffer to use normal background-color, with some opacity and blur on it...

Here is example: http://codecanyon.net/item/translucent-jquery-banner-rotator-slideshow/801607?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=VF

That slider have translucent and blurry description bar and that is exactly what I want...

I found one more example here: http://www.blurjs.com/

But I don't want javascript. I would love if it can be done with css3.

I don't know if that slider use javascript or css for that?

Anyone know to code something like that with css? Thank you for your time.

Comment: don't really see why so many downvotes... aside from a little ignorance his question doesn't seem to be in breach of the faqs

Comment: All these demos use javascript for a reason. Upvoted because it's not a bad question at all!

Comment: Thanks to both... Um, well I'll use that blur.js in that case. I have no other choices. Just thought that there may be a possibility with css3 cause I will be using way too many javascripts.

Comment: -1 I don't know how this could qualify as a *specific programming problem*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slider you linked to is using the canvas element, which requires javascript to manipulate.

What you want is not doable with CSS alone - you need javascript, but it's possible [svg](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_fegaussianblur.asp) can handle it. I don't have enough svg experience to know for sure, however.